# I have an app that needs to open another app using a custom URL scheme. Can I find out the version number of the app I need to open somehow?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have an app that needs to open another app using a custom URL scheme. Can I find out the version number of the app I need to open somehow?

The company who made the app has changed their URL scheme and so the one I am calling requires version 2.7 of their app. Is there any way to detect which version of the app the user has installed, and then prompt them to update the app (before we call into it) if the version number is too low (< 2.7 in this case)?

Thanks

Comment: Did they register a second scheme that you can see if a handler is installed for?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UIApplication -(BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` to see if the URL scheme you are using is supported or not. You can then proceed to test for the second scheme and so on.